# How To Loop in A Dataset and Delete Specific Fields in All Feature Classes With ArcPY

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-10.0

How can I use ArcPy to loop into all Feature Classes in a dataset `Structure`in  Geodatabase `GEWA.gdb` and delete Two fields of them called `MapBy` and `EnabledBy` if they exist? (All of feature classes have the `Mapby` but only some of them has the `EnabledBy`).

[image]

Comment: A Question asking about how to do something in *code* should include a code attempt and details of what happens when you try it, including any error messages encountered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\GEWA.gdb\Structure'
dropfields=['MapBy','EnabledBy']
featurelist=arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
for feature in featurelist:
    arcpy.DeleteField_management(in_table=feature,drop_field=dropfields)
```

Comment: Nice.  I didn't know DeleteField_management would work if the field didn't exist.  It just throws a warning.

Comment: Thanks BERA, can you just let me know how can I get access to feature names as well?

Comment: I tried `     print feature.name + "Updated"` in the loop but it doesnt know the name propert

Comment: 'print feature' but dont do that. You will print all feature names including the features where no fields get dropped